# Is it legal to write PhD theses for other people?

Tags: united-states, european-union, germany

I got an offer from a newspaper to make my story public on how I wrote a lot of PhD's for paying customers. Do I have to fear legal consequences and what would happen if I make it public (without naming the customers)? I didn't wrote in "dangerous" fields like chemistry or medicine. Only in following fields:

- Physics
- Mathematics
- Computer Science
- Biology
- Philosophy
- German
- French
- Law
- Economy
- Scandinavistic
- Molecular Biology
- Psychology
- Etc.

As far as I know, I don't have to fear any legal consequences. But I wanted to ask here to be sure. And do I have to fear problems with lawyers when I go to public with my story? Like they will force me to name my customers? I want to protect my customers - it would be bad for business.

**This is a totally theoretical question. I am not asking for legal advice.**

Comment: To be clear: by "wrote a lot of PhD's" you mean "wrote a lot of PhD *theses*", correct? I ask because a lot of PhD programs require coursework and multiple published works in academic journals, culminating in a final thesis. Did you (theoretically) write some or all of these, or just the final thesis?

Comment: _theoretically_ I only wrote the final thesis. Sometimes a bachelor project and a master project too ... and sometimes I wrote project work too ... but mostly it was the final thesis and writing academic articles being published in peer-reviewed articles. _theoretically_ of course

Comment: I'd be most worried about the possibility that one of your alleged customers might sue you for libel or defamation.  In most jurisdictions, it's a defense if you can show that your claims are true - but trials are always uncertain, and defending the case could be very expensive in terms of legal fees.  I would definitely consult a lawyer before doing anything.

Comment: Wouldn't this amount to defrauding the university and everyone from whom the student got anything because of the degree? I find it far-fetched that someone wrote lots of Ph.D. theses in mathematics, physics, molecular biology, and computer science.  And why is chemistry "dangerous" where those fields are not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some states in the United States have laws specifically about selling theses (etc.) For example, see [Pennsylvania Code Title 18 - CRIMES AND OFFENSES Chapter 73 - Trade and Commerce  7324 - Unlawful sale of dissertations, theses and term papers](http://law.justia.com/codes/pennsylvania/2010/title-18/chapter-73/7324):

> No person shall sell or offer for distribution any dissertation,
>        thesis, term paper, essay, report or other written assignment to
>        any student enrolled in a university, college, academy, school
>        or any other institution within the Commonwealth of Pennsylvania
>        knowing, or under the circumstances having reason to know, that
>        said assignment is intended for submission either in whole or
>        substantial part under said student's name to such educational
>        institution in fulfillment of the requirement for a degree,
>        diploma, certificate or course of study.

Similar laws exist in many other states. For example, [California](http://law.justia.com/codes/california/2005/edc/66400-66406.html), [Florida](http://law.justia.com/codes/florida/2010/TitleXLVI/chapter877/877_17.html), [Texas](http://law.justia.com/codes/texas/2005/pe/007.00.000032.00.html), [Virginia](http://law.justia.com/codes/virginia/2006/toc1802000/18.2-505.html), [Oregon](http://law.justia.com/codes/oregon/2009/165.html), [New York](http://law.justia.com/codes/new-york/2013/edn/title-1/article-5/part-1/213-b).